# Livereload not reloading static files on chrome for spring

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I added this to pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

At application properties, i have this

```
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true

spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.resources.cache.period=0

spring.devtools.restart.enabled=false
spring.devtools.livereload.port=35729
```

I have a simple html, about.html under templates, it has only string:

```
sada
```

I have chrome and plugin added. While app is up, i can see livereload connected.

When i run the app, i see this in logs:

```
2020-01-21 13:39:00.041  INFO 1288 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-01-21 13:39:00.185  WARN 1288 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
```

But when i change about.html to this:

```
qqq
```

And refresh lots of times, i cant see any different.

I use intellijidea.

I also did not enable auto build because i dont want it to restart. I only want to reload.

I also did this:

```
To open the registry, just press SHIFT+CTRL+A. In the registry window, enable the “compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running” check-box.
```

So, why cant it reload?

Before, when i refresh page, i  was seeing changes on different project. I did not change anything on browser or ide. I put same properties to `appproperties`

Comment: See [Configure application update policies with devtools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-boot.html#configure-application-update-policies-with-devtools) and also [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-159298#focus=streamItem-27-2719444.0-0).

Comment: I did this `From the On 'Update' action list, select a policy. You can update resources only,` but still can not update the html